# Possession with common and proper nouns in same sentence

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

She was in town for her brother’s, Brett’s, birthday.
or
She was in town for her brother, Brett’s, birthday.
or
She was in town for her brother’s, Brett’s, birthday.
or
?

Comment: "She was in town for her brother Brett’s, birthday." Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: The possessive apostrophe-s applies to the whole phrase "her brother Brett". HTH.